# Gitlab EE - Gitlab Pages setup without wildcard domain

Tags: gitlab, self-hosting, gitlab-api, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-pages

I can't figure out how to setup Gitlab Pages on my self-hosted Gitlab instance without wildcard domains. For example, I have 1 server with 3 public IP addresses and domain names:

- 10.8.0.10 (git.example.com) - main GitLab instance
- 10.8.0.11 (registry.example.com) - container registry
- 10.8.0.12 (pages.example.com) - GitLab Pages

Then' I set up the Omnibus config `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` like that:

```rb
external_url 'https://git.example.com'
nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['10.8.0.10']


registry_external_url 'https://registry.example.com'
registry_nginx['enable'] = true
registry_nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['10.8.0.11']
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/git.example.com.crt"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/git.example.com.key"

pages_external_url 'https://pages.example.com'
pages_nginx['enable'] = false
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
gitlab_pages['cert'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/pages.example.com.crt"
gitlab_pages['cert_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/pages.example.com.key"
gitlab_pages['external_http'] = ['10.8.0.12:80']
gitlab_pages['external_https'] = ['10.8.0.12:443']
```

For example, I have a project located on https://git.example.com/somegroupname/project. I can get an access to container registry of this project by https://registry.example.com/somegroupname/project and pull the Docker image with command `docker pull registry.example.com/somegroupname/project`.

I know that GitLab Pages set namespaces as the A-record. In my case, it sets up like https://somegroupname.pages.example.com/project, but I don't have an availability to use such domain names. Instead of that, I want to place the namespace in path like that:
https://pages.example.com/somegroupname/project
but I can't find any settings or parameters to enable this behavior, and it doesn't work with the current setup. All the pages stored correctly in default path `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages/`. Can please somebody help me?

Comment: it appears not to be possible as of late 2021. Here's an open issue requesting exactly that: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17584

Answer (score 0):

That should now be supported with [GitLab 16.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/12/21/gitlab-16-7-released/#use-gitlab-pages-without-a-wildcard-dns) (December 2023):

> ### Use GitLab pages without a wildcard DNS
>
> Previously, to create a GitLab Pages project, you needed a domain formatted like `name.example.io` or `name.pages.example.io`.
> This requirement meant you had to set up wildcard DNS records and SSL/TLS certificates.
>
> In GitLab 16.7, you can set up a GitLab Pages project *without* a DNS wildcard. This feature is an experiment.
>
> Removing the requirement for wildcard certificates eases administrative overhead associated with GitLab pages. Some customers can’t use GitLab Pages because of organizational restrictions on wildcard DNS records or certificates.
>
> We welcome feedback related to this feature in [issue 434372](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/434372).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/#pages-domain-without-wildcard-dns) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17584).